# ajax success html response data content not loaded in the jquery-ui modal box

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

i want to open the jquery-ui modal popup box after my ajax success call complete. Currently it shows nothing only browsers console get successful ajax call.

Dialog1 id reside in my postUrl page where I process all my ajax post data. I want all the html content loading in jquery-ui modal box.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#dialog1" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false
    });
    $('#btnPreview').on('click',function(){
        var formData = $('#listForm').serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/test/dealPreview.php',
            method:'POST',
            data: formData,   
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#dialog1").html(data);
                $("#dialog1").dialog("open");
            }
        });
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: try removing your `dataType` option.

Comment: Is it your actual HTML? I do not see `<script></script>` tags around your script.

Comment: copied the data from my code forgot to include script tag my actual html data in my posturl page dealpreview.php @lolka_bolka

Comment: remove the dataType option still no success @Todd

Comment: so, open dev tools. Pass in textStatus and jqXHR parameters into `success:function()` beside the data arg. In your success handler, type `console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4), textStatus, jqXHR);`, reload the page and see what is printed to the console.

Comment: can you make a js fiddle?